# Как перебрать несколько условий в for на php?

Tags: php

Имеется:

```
$help = array(1;2;3;6;7,9)
$arr = explode(";", $help));
$colnum=400;
for ($i = 1; $i <= colnum; $i++) {
 if ($i==$arr)continue;
 echo '$i,';
}
```

Должно получиться 4,5,8,10,11,12,13,14...400

Как правильно написать управляющую конструкцию for (возможно с использованием while) для успешной выдачи необходимых значений?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете проверять с помощью функции in_array.

```
if(!in_array($i, $arr)){echo '$i,'}
```

Comment: Думал система пробежится по условию раз и второе число из условия не будет учитываться, по этому и не использовал, а нет, все хорошо.

Answer (score 3):

```
$arr = [1,2,3,6,7,9];
$range = range(1, 400);
$result = array_diff($range, $arr);
```

Comment: Ваше решение, также верное